# On Android app, should you explicitly set all old used variables to null as my app has memory overuse crashes

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

When you start a new intent from a current intent in Android, should you explicitly set all old, used variables to null as my app has memory overuse crashes.

The app crashes when I start the new intent sometimes because there is insufficient memory so I'm trying to find a way of reducing the memory used as I have purely relied on garbage collection and now the app's java files are up to 5000 lines long

Answer (score 0):

> should you explicitly set all old used variables to null

**No.** If we say about variable instances, It will be picked up by **Garbage Collector** as soon as they are isolated from the references. So resetting a variables back to `null` doesn't make any sense.

About the memory leaks, you can use [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to identify memory leaks in your `Activities`. Leak Canary got pretty easy implementation.

Comment: Thanks Wiz, I'll invest time into Leak Canary tonight for my app

Comment: Good luck for that. You may up vote the ans if it happens useful.

Comment: Sadly, not enough rep - Qn - why do you  want it upvoted? Do you people rewarded financially for being upvoted?